# CoreAnimation setFrameCenterRotation Doesn't Animate Properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation

I'm having a bit of trouble with getting CoreAnimation to rotate an NSView about its center point. All I want to do is rotate an NSView while keeping its center point static so that the object appears to rotate in place.

The way I chose to do this involves the use of the `animator` property in NSView. The code is as follows:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0];

[[view animator] setFrameCenterRotation:45.0];

[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Where `view` is the NSView that I am trying to rotate. The result of this code makes the object abruptly shift to the right somewhat then does the rotation. The final result is correct, but the animation doesn't look right because of the movement it makes in the beginning. I'm assuming that this is because the way that `setFrameCenterRotation:` works is that it shifts the frame origin to the view's center point first, then makes the rotation.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way, perhaps, to rotate an NSView about the center? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure NSView layer backed (Core Animation enabled), animator proxy would otherwise animate without CA. Do this with -setWantsLayer:YES, or by checking the corresponding option for that view in IB.

Second, set the layer anchor point to 0.5, 0.5:

```
view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
```

Third, you may need direct layer interaction if you can't get what you want, but first try with AppKit API's, as it preserves mouse events, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems I have another problem. The anchorPoint for the layer definitely appears to be the source of the issue, but shouldn't it be (0.5, 0.5) by default? It says so explicitly in Apple's documentation. Anyway, my problem now happens when I have an `NSViewAnimation` run at the same time as the rotation animation. When the NSViewAnimation runs at the same time, setting the anchor point does nothing! But when I do not run the NSViewAnimation, it works fine. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Thanks, @Zanneth! I was having a similar problem, and your comment gave me the necessary clue to solve it. I was rotating the root layer of an imageView. Its anchorPoint read out at 0, 0, bottom left per standard coordinate orientation. I could set it to .5, .5, but it would be ignored, just as you experienced. Moving both the image and the animation to the sublayer solved the problem for me. Apparently whenever a view or its root layer animates, it knocks out the anchorPoint. Hope you were able to work around this in your project.

Comment: How do you move the animation to the 'sublayer'? I can set the anchorpoint to 0.5 but then the view suddenly 'jumps' to it's 0,0 origin but along with its center.

Comment: I think he is saying that you explicitly create a sublayer, which is then *not* managed by NSView. NSView maintains a lot of properties of the top-level layer (see http://jwilling.com/blog/osx-animations/), but adding a sublayer may indeed workaround all those issues (you don't touch the view-layer, but only the sublayer). Need to try this :-)